# HSQLDB - integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; BLOCKS_PK table: BLOCKS

Tags: java, hsqldb

I'm new to HSQLDB and just got this error and I'm not able to find any solution to this on the internet, seems like I'm missing something ^^

My application is currently not doing anything else than creating two tables if they don't exist already.

This is my code that handles the HSQLDB:

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver" );
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("ERROR: failed to load HSQLDB JDBC driver.");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}

try {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:"+mi.getDataFolder().getPath()+"\\data\\storage;hsqldb.lock_file=false", "SA", "");
    connection.prepareStatement(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Punishments (" +
            "id INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY," +
            "name VARCHAR(16)," +
            "uuid VARCHAR(35)," +
            "reason VARCHAR(100)," +
            "operator VARCHAR(16)," +
            "punishmentType VARCHAR(16)," +
            "start BIGINT," +
            "end BIGINT," +
            "calculation VARCHAR(50))"
    ).execute();
    connection.prepareStatement(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PunishmentHistory (" +
            "id INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY," +
            "name VARCHAR(16)," +
            "uuid VARCHAR(35)," +
            "reason VARCHAR(100)," +
            "operator VARCHAR(16)," +
            "punishmentType VARCHAR(16)," +
            "start BIGINT," +
            "end BIGINT," +
            "calculation VARCHAR(50))"
    ).execute();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The first two or so times that I run the code, it works fine but at some point, I keep getting this error:

```
    [22:22:21 FATAL]: statement error processing log - open continuedplugins\AdvancedBan\data\storage.log line: 2
    org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; BLOCKS_PK table: BLOCKS
            at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[AdvancedBan-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
            at org.hsqldb.Constraint.getException(Unknown Source) ~[AdvancedBan-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
            at org.hsqldb.index.IndexAVLMemory.insert(Unknown Source) ~[AdvancedBan-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
            at org.hsqldb.persist.RowStoreAVL.indexRow(Unknown Source) ~[AdvancedBan-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
            at org.hsqldb.TransactionManager2PL.addInsertAction(Unknown Source) ~[AdvancedBan-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
            at org.hsqldb.Session.addInsertAction(Unknown Source) ~[AdvancedBan-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
            at org.hsqldb.Table.insertNoCheckFromLog(Unknown Source) ~[AdvancedBan-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
            at org.hsqldb.persist.ScriptRunner.runScript(Unknown Source) [AdvancedBan-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
            at org.hsqldb.persist.ScriptRunner.runScript(Unknown Source) [AdvancedBan-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
            at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.processLog(Unknown Source) [AdvancedBan-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
            at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.open(Unknown Source) [AdvancedBan-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
            at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.open(Unknown Source) [AdvancedBan-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
            at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Unknown Source) [AdvancedBan-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
            at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Unknown Source) [AdvancedBan-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
            at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source) [AdvancedBan-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
            at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source) [AdvancedBan-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
            at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source) [AdvancedBan-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
            at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source) [AdvancedBan-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
            at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source) [AdvancedBan-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
            at me.leoko.advancedban.manager.DatabaseManager.setup(DatabaseManager.java:69) [AdvancedBan-2.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
[...]
```

This is an example of how .log file looks after I get the error:

```
/*C1*/SET SCHEMA SYSTEM_LOBS
INSERT INTO BLOCKS VALUES(0,2147483647,0)
COMMIT
/*C2*/SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Punishments (id INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,name VARCHAR(16),uuid VARCHAR(35),reason VARCHAR(100),operator VARCHAR(16),punishmentType VARCHAR(16),start BIGINT,end BIGINT,calculation VARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PunishmentHistory (id INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,name VARCHAR(16),uuid VARCHAR(35),reason VARCHAR(100),operator VARCHAR(16),punishmentType VARCHAR(16),start BIGINT,end BIGINT,calculation VARCHAR(50))
DISCONNECT
/*C4*/SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Punishments (id INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,name VARCHAR(16),uuid VARCHAR(35),reason VARCHAR(100),operator VARCHAR(16),punishmentType VARCHAR(16),start BIGINT,end BIGINT,calculation VARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PunishmentHistory (id INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,name VARCHAR(16),uuid VARCHAR(35),reason VARCHAR(100),operator VARCHAR(16),punishmentType VARCHAR(16),start BIGINT,end BIGINT,calculation VARCHAR(50))
DISCONNECT
/*C3*/SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Punishments (id INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,name VARCHAR(16),uuid VARCHAR(35),reason VARCHAR(100),operator VARCHAR(16),punishmentType VARCHAR(16),start BIGINT,end BIGINT,calculation VARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PunishmentHistory (id INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,name VARCHAR(16),uuid VARCHAR(35),reason VARCHAR(100),operator VARCHAR(16),punishmentType VARCHAR(16),start BIGINT,end BIGINT,calculation VARCHAR(50))
DISCONNECT
/*C3*/SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Punishments (id INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,name VARCHAR(16),uuid VARCHAR(35),reason VARCHAR(100),operator VARCHAR(16),punishmentType VARCHAR(16),start BIGINT,end BIGINT,calculation VARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PunishmentHistory (id INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,name VARCHAR(16),uuid VARCHAR(35),reason VARCHAR(100),operator VARCHAR(16),punishmentType VARCHAR(16),start BIGINT,end BIGINT,calculation VARCHAR(50))
```

I'm using Version 2.4.0 of HSQLDB but have also tried this with some older version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Thank you for any piece of advice in advance.

Comment: You are probably using an old version of HSQLDB. Try the latest.

Comment: @fredt I'm using 2.4.0 of HSQLDB which should be the latest, also edited my question. Thanks anyway for trying to help :)

Comment: Add  connection.prepareStatement("CHECKPOINT").execute() after the other statements and it should fix the issue;

Comment: @fredt Thanks, that solved a part of my issue but then a slightly different exception occurred. I've done some more research about the "CHECKPOINT" Query, as I've never heard about it and found out that I should call the "SHUTDOWN" Query in the end when my application is being closed. So that solved all the exceptions. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @Leoko Hii, I'm doing JUnit testing and getting the same error for uniqueness. Could be please assist with the code ? and where that code needs to be paste.

Comment: @Saad In my case it solved the issue to run
`connection.prepareStatement("SHUTDOWN").execute();`
before exiting the application.
Here is my full code:
[Code on GitHub](https://github.com/DevLeoko/AdvancedBan/blob/master/src/main/java/me/leoko/advancedban/manager/DatabaseManager.java#L79) (The DatabaseManager.java also supports MySQL so don't get confused ;))

Answer (score 1):

I just had to call the "SHUTDOWN" SQL Command in the end, when my application is being closed and from time to time the "CHECKPOINT" SQL Command.

Thanks for helping me solve that issue.